# how to return a type from a protocol in swift

Tags: swift

```
import Foundation
protocol R {
func random() -> Double
}
class Dice {
    let sides: Int
    let generator: R
    init(sides: Int, generator: R) {
       self.sides = sides
       self.generator = generator
       }
   func roll() -> Int {
      return Int(generator.random() * Double(sides)) + 1 
     }
}
 var d6 = Dice(sides: 6, generator: LinearCongruentialGenerator())
 for _ in 1...5 {
 print("Random dice roll is \(d6.roll())")
 }
 // Random dice roll is 3
 // Random dice roll is 5
 // Random dice roll is 4
 // Random dice roll is 5
 // Random dice roll is 4
```

I was reading the article in swift documentation in using a protocol as a type and  what I don't understand what is LinearCongruentialGenerator() and how come the generator.random() in this code

```
return Int(generator.random() * Double(sides)) + 1
```

is able to return, even though it was not defined, it was just declared.
also in the website, the documentation said

> The generator property is of type RandomNumberGenerator. Therefore, you can set it to an instance of any type that adopts the RandomNumberGenerator protocol. Nothing else is required of the instance you assign to this property, except that the instance must adopt the RandomNumberGenerator protocol

I tried my code and it was like this:

```
   class return_protocol: R {
   
      func random() -> Double {

        return 10.0
      {
        
    }



   let return_instace = return_protocol()
   let x = return_instace.random()
   var instance = Dice(sides: 6, generator: x)
```

and I'm stuck now.
how can I create an instance that I can pass it as an argument to the generator

Comment: You should pass `return_instace` instead of `x`.

Comment: You pass the variable `return_instance`: `Dice(sides: 6, generator: return_instance)`. Your terminology is a bit off though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your example, `x` is type `Double` and you are trying to pass it to Dice constructor. Instead, pass your return_instance

```
let return_instace = return_protocol() // -> Type return_protocol: R
let x = return_instace.random() // -> Type Double
var instance = Dice(sides: 6, generator: x) // generator expects Type R, not Double
```